# google app engine: new version doesn't appear

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, version

I have made an update on Google App Engine with a small fix and I got:

```
Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
```

However, when I open the website, there is still old version. I have changed version to 2 in app.yaml, before running update. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the new version to be the active version in the Admin console. Click the 'Versions' link, and make your new version the Default.

Comment: I haven't noticed that in the console, but indeed it helped (I turned of DEBUG, so now I can't see the error ;-)). Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: OK, now it even works and displays what I have returned in django view. Thanks again :-)